# C++ 03 change a macro to template

Tags: c++, templates

I want to change the following macro into a template in c++ 03. 
Is it even useful to change this type of macro to a templated function?
Are method pointers useful here?

What is the best approach for this? Is it a better way to use a MACRO or a template in order to achieve this?

```
namespace BP{

class PrintClass{
public:
    PrintClass(){}

    void printOne(int i) const{
        std::cout << "1" << i << "\n";
    }

    void printTwo(int i) const{
        std::cout << "2" << i << "\n";
    }

};

class TestClass{
private:
    int d_one;
    int d_two;

public:

    TestClass() : d_one(1), d_two(2){}

    const int getOne() const{
        return d_one;
    }
    const int getTwo() const {
        return d_two;
    }

};
}

#define PRINT_MACRO(print, NUM) \
{\
    TestClass t; \
    int r = t.get##NUM();\
    print(r);\
}
int main(){
    using namespace BP;
    PrintClass p;
    PRINT_MACRO(p.printOne, Two);
    PRINT_MACRO(p.printTwo, One);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I would typically advise simply writing "getOne" or "getTwo" and not using the macro at all.

Comment: `PRINT_MACRO(p.printOne, Two)` is only 4 characters shorter than `p.printOne(TestClass().getTwo())`. Just saying.